# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Trying to upload images to Firebase

Tags: firebase, exc-bad-access

I am trying to upload images to Firebase like this:

```
let storageRef = Storage().reference()
if let uploadData = self.profileImageView.image!.pngData() {
                storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error as Any)
                        return
                    }
                    print(metadata as Any)
                })
            }
```

and it's redirecting me to this code here:

```
 - (void)dispatchAsync:(void (^)(void))block {
  dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, block);
}
```

It does not get past the if let statement. (if let uploadData = self.profileImageView.image!.pngData())

I have no idea why. It does not give me any additional error messages in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by king_T did not work for me. The issue is related to this line

```
Storage().reference()
```

As noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119944/ios-firebase-storage-file-upload-object-does-not-exist) you should use

```
Storage.storage().reference()
```

It's very unintuitive.

Comment: Very annoying! Took me at least an hour to recognize and find the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar issues, and I solved it by compressing my image.

```
let scaledimage = self.profileImageView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
let storageRef = Storage().reference()
if let uploadData = scaledimage {
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error as Any)
                    return
                }
                print(metadata as Any)
            })
}
```

that solved it for me.